# TIdText missing from Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, indy

In order to send email via GMail, I finally upgraded to Indy 10. Whilst I can send simple emails via GMail, I suddenly find that my complicated email program which sends HTML text no longer compiles - I am missing the TIdText component.

I have searched my computer and there is no TIDMessage.pas file, although there is a dcu file which is dated today. I am using Delphi 7.

Where can I find the missing component?

Comment: It seems to me that you never actually searched for the "missing" class. You only searched for a file name, and *assumed* that the file contained the thing you wanted. Searching for text is easy; don't let it stand in the way of doing what you really mean. `grep -ri tidtext *`

Comment: Or use the IDE's Search -> Find In Files. I can't work very long in Delphi without either grep or find-in-files, or Notepad++'s find-in-files. Downvoting for failure to search your disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Delphi are you using?  And which edition (professional, etc.)?

On my machine, there’s an `IdText.pas` file located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\Indy\Indy10\Protocols\IdText.pas** (I believe this is Delphi 2010, for which I have a Professional license).

Comment: I don't have a 'protocols' subdirectory. I'm using Delphi 7 Enterprise.

Comment: It doesn't matter which Delphi you have since you installed Indy yourself.

Comment: There *is* a protocols directory buried somewhere in the structure, and yes, there is a IdText file!

Comment: Don't post a question on StackOverflow when Searching your hard disk is enough, please.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `IdText` unit to your uses clause. In older versions of Indy, this unit did not exist. In Indy 10 this is a new unit that now contains `TIdText` which used to live in `IdMessage`.

If you are also using `TIdAttachment`, then you'll have the same problem. The unit needed in that case is `IdAttachment`. And so on and so on.

Comment: I was savvy enough to change TIdAttachment to TIdAttachmentFile which helps.

Comment: What David said applies to `TIdAttachmentFile` as well. In Indy 9, all of the TIdMessage-related classes were located in the `IdMessage.pas` unit. In Indy 10, they were all separated into their own units: `IdMessageParts.pas`, `IdText.pas`, `IdAttachment.pas`, `IdAttachmentFile.pas`, `IdAttachmentMemory.pas`, etc.